# Looking for an icon set like this one

Tags: icons, icon-themes

I'm looking for a working plastic looking icon set like the one below:

[image: icons]

Source: [Plastico icons by kxmylo | DeviantArt](http://kxmylo.deviantart.com/art/Plastico-icons-390271064)

Unfortunately these icons are too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your /home/nuc/.icons isnt actualy a folder but a copy of Plastico-icons.tar renamed to .icons

Use the mv command instead to avoid mistakes like this, or man cp

```
rm -rf /home/nuc/.icons     (only once to delete your .icons who is actualy a file, not a folder)
mkdir /home/nuc/.icons      (only once, if directory is not existing).
tar -xvf /tmp/Plastico-icons.tar -C /home/nuc/.icons/  (to unpack your .tar to your folder).
```

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that the above icons are sized too small.

Comment: Is there a way to set sizes via the tweak tool? (Haven't found it.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure why you are looking for one a like when you can have that one?
Download is available through DeviantArt - please check the license!

```
http://www.deviantart.com/download/390271064/plastico_icons_by_kxmylo-d6gcv2w.png?token=d4b10e7f26dc6cf634c0356b29f3761189509ac2&ts=1442343673
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to install. Other themes provide a command line command and I then can choose it under the tweak tool.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=3757

You may find that useful.

Comment: `nuc@nuc:/tmp$ cp Plastico-icons.tar /home/nuc/.icons
nuc@nuc:/tmp$ cd /home/nuc/.icons
bash: cd: /home/nuc/.icons: Is no directory`